# Spring Property Placeholder - Ignore Inverted Commas

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I am running a java project on a tomcat server on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk
On the Beanstalk config page, I set an environment variable to be used by my application.

I use this environment variable to load up the correct properties files for my application

I have my property specified as follows - ENVIRONMENT - TEST
This is how I am trying to load the properties file

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:config/properties/Database-${ENVIRONMENT}.properties"/>
```

When I start my server - I get a warning message

```
class path resource [config/properties/Database-"LOCAL".properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

The inverted commas are added to the system property and spring seems to count them in the variable name

Does anyone know how I can get spring to ignore these inverted commas?

Thank you
Damien

Comment: This should not happen. How are you passing ENVIRONMENT=LOCAL  to the application?

Comment: Amazon Elastic Beanstalk is doing this. From posting on the Amazon Forum, fols say that setting the property ENVIRONMENT=LOCAL or ENVIRONMENT="LOCAL" shouldnt make a difference. Here is a link to the question i posted https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=643341&#643341

Comment: Looks like it makes some difference. Are you putting quotes around the property value in aws explorer ?if so remove it and try.

Comment: Im not no - i am adding the property without the quotes. Amazon seems to be adding the quotes to all the properties that it adds

Comment: Yes. I think this is because "real" tomcat is getting updated and expected scripts are not getting run - have a look at this https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=115043   it says `Elastic Beanstalk has a special tomcat7 startup script that handles double quotation marks specially (we do need them), but this special script is overridden when updating Tomcat via Yum.`

Comment: thanks for that. its a complicated process just to handle double quotes. Funny how this was fine on the default Amazon Elastic Beanstalk on the latest old AMI with version 64bit Amazon Linux 2015.03 v1.3.1 running Tomcat 8 Java 8

Comment: I just tried creating a listener in my web.xml that will remove any inverted commas from the environment variable prior to loading my environment specific properties. Not ideal but it will do until I can get a proper solution to this problem